# How to stop a method from other method

Tags: methods

It's possible to call another method to check something, like a boolean, and stop it (return or wathever) from it? i mean:

Method 1:
code
call method 2: ?
code

Method 2:
if(wathever){
make method 1 return
}
else{
continue
}

EDIT: yes java sorry, thanks for answers! Also yes i know how to use booleans this way, this didn't solved my question, don't want to check a returned boolean, i want to directly make the method 1 return, i suppose is not possible but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way to stop a method if something doesn't check?

Comment: I'm wondering whether you're looking for `return;` or `longjmp()`...

Comment: In which language ? C# ? Java ? JavaScript ? etc...

Comment: @Berkay [LOLcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOLCODE)

Answer (score 2):

Oh, and just to actually keep my promise about LOLcode, here's a little function that returns or does something else based on its only Boolean argument:

```
HOW DUZ I BREAK_OUTTA_FUNCTION YR FLAG
    IZ FLAG WIN, O RLY?
        YA RLY                                    BTW if flag is `WIN` (true)
           GTFO                                   BTW return
        NO WAY
            BTW do something else if `flag' is LOSE (false)
    OIC
IF U SAY SO
```

Answer (score 0):

So you basically want a way for a method to force the invoking method to exit?

Return an out parameter or boolean from the method to indicate to the invoking method that it needs to exit.

```
public void Method1()
{
    if(!method2())
      return;

    // do stuff
}

public bool Method2()
{
    if(check) {
       return false;
    }

    // do other stuff
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean return values / a boolean conditional based on the return value of method two. But you can not really forward a return statement. My example is language indiscriminate since you did not provide a language.

```
def methodOne(): 
    if (!methodTwo()):
        return
    else:
        <code>

def methodTwo():
    if (whatever):
        return false
    else:
        <code>
```